# import.meta.url gets path of source file instead of compiled file

Tags: node.js, webpack, electron

Since `__dirname` is undefined in a typescript electron project, I have resorted to

```
import * as path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
```

However, this new `__dirname` gets the directory of the original source file instead of the compiled file. (Paths ends up being `/src/something.ts` instead of `/dist/something.js`)

Is there a way to get the path of the compiled file being run? Am I missing some webpack, tsconfig settings?

(Unfortunately, `app.getAppPath()` also seems to rely on `__dirname`)

**EDIT:** I am trying to load an angular app inside electron through the `protocol.registerFileProtocol` since plain relative or `file://` links to not seem to be loaded:

```
protocol.registerFileProtocol('resource', (request, callback) => {
    let url = request.url.substr(11); // Remove the resource://
    callback(path.join(app.getAppPath(), '/', url));
    // or
    callback(path.join(__dirname, '/', url));
});
```

Comment: What do you get in `__filename`?

Comment: Did you look at the generated code and see what webpack turned it into?  Since the point of webpack is to collect things from all over your file system into one piece, it's not surprising that you can't refer to the file system.  There are probably ways for you to include in your webpack whatever it is you want to use `__filename` for.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You are asking about a problem with `__filename` in a webpack generated output without telling us what the real problem is (what you're trying to do with `__filename`) or why you want it.  Telling us the real problem would likely enable people to tell you how to properly use webpack when you have other resources you need to reference.

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the Angular app inside the webpack bundle?